# NO_PUBKEY error when updating 22.0.4

Tags: apt, updates, 22.04, software-sources, gnome-keyring

```
An error occurred during the signature verification. 
The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. 
GPG error: http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease: 
The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: 
  NO_PUBKEY 40976EAF437D05B5 NO_PUBKEY 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32
```

Comment: Why do you have an active 16.04 (`xenial-security`) source in a 22.04 system? Audit your apt sources.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I restore the default repositories?](https://askubuntu.com/q/124017/)